# How to check for DLL file architecture and build type in Conan `[imports]`?

Tags: c++, conan

My project has `Relase_x64`, `Release_Win32`, `Debug_x64` and `Debug_Win32` folders inside the `build` folder. I need the Conan script `conanfile.txt` to copy the correct DLLs from the `bin` folder of the package to the correct folder inside my project build folder.

In the [`conanfile.txt`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/using_packages/conanfile_txt.html#imports) file, there's the *imports* option:

```
[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./bin # Copies all dll files from packages bin folder to my "bin" folder
```

But instead of the `./bin` folder I need to specify the correct *build_architecture* folder for the DLL to be copied in.

How do I get the correct DLL and copy to the correct folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate it into your build project, you can't just hard code a path and expect it to work. For example, in a pure Visual C++ (MS) project, the way I do it is as a post-build step where I call

```
conan install . -s arch=x86 -s build_type=Debug -s compiler.runtime=MDd -s compiler.version=15
```

I have one of these entries for each architecture and build type in the C++ project file. You also need to import `conanbuildinfo.props` into your project.

To specify your libraries, you need a file called `conanfile.txt` in the same folder with contents like this:

```
[requires]
3026563/4.0.2@TRU/stable

[generators]
visual_studio
```

This is trivial to understand, but very tedious and manual to first set up.

All of this can be automated with Cmake projects, which has conan integration (or rather, conan has better Cmake integration). Look up the details online, but the basic idea is that you derive your own class from `ConanFile` and then override the requirements function to provide the libraries and version numbers you want, and the rest of the system takes care of getting the correct architecture and build type:

```
def requirements(self):
    self.requires ("3037383/3.0.0@TRU/master_A320")  # Core library
    self.requires ("3019048/0.0.4@TRU/stable")              # FWC_H2-F9D library
    self.requires ("A320-Autogen/1.2.34@TRU/stable")    # 3018957 - A320 AUTOGEN library
    self.requires ("A320-STD-NFL/5.6.0@TRU/stable")         # A320-STD-NFL
```

Comment: I have added the property sheets and I have a conanfile.txt in my project. For example I have defined:

`[requires]
3026563/4.0.2@TRU/stable

[generators]
visual_studio

[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ..\build\Release_x64`

But I want this imports function to work for all build types and architectures.

Comment: So read the first part of my answer.

Comment: The ``visual_studio`` generator is legacy and no longer maintained. Recommended to use ``MSBuildDeps`` and ``MSBuildToolchain`` (both). Also ``imports`` mechanism is being deprecated in favor of explicit ``copy(self, ...)`` (note ``from conan.tools.files import copy``) in the ``generate()`` method of a conanfile.py